# MySQL query table into JSON Object in Array

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create a post which has a properties of comments. A comment consists of an author and the actual text. I created a table named posts and a table named comments. They are connected through the post title.

Is there a possibility to get this output:

Col1: posts.author 
Col2: posts.title 
Col3: Comments(shown below)

```
[{"comment_author": 'The author', "text": 'the text'},...]
```

I searched for so long but did not find a fitting solution that actually works.

```
posts:
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | title     | author |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | title one | fabi   |
+----+-----------+--------+

comments:
+----+---------------+----------------+-------------+
| id | comment_title | comment_author | comment     |
+----+---------------+----------------+-------------+
|  1 | title one     | peter          | my comment  |
|  2 | title one     | mio            | another one |
+----+---------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: which mysql version you are using?

Comment: I am using this version:  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.6-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

You can get

```
Col1: posts.author Col2: posts.title Col3: Comments
```

Using the following query

```
Select p.author, p.title, c.comment  FROM posts p JOIN comments c ON p.title = c.comment_title;
```

I would recommend that you use posts.id as a foreign key rather than the comment_title.